# Facebook api request handling

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

**Hey everyone,**

i'm building a facebook application with the **javascript sdk** and i want to let the user invite one or more friends to use the application.

i want to let the user open the request dialog and choose his friends to invite.

i have 2 questions about this issue:

1) is this the right way to do so? or shuld i use regular message dialog?

2) i read here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
   that i must delete the request after it has been accepted.
   how can i delete it? do i have to store the request id on my side? if so, how?
   and how can i know if the request accepted? and than how do i delete it?
   i cant find answers for those issues in the facebook docs.

Thanks a lot